# After Insert trigger Header and Detail tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have a program that captures orders into two SQL tables.  One is  a header table with order info that has OrderID as auto increment PK. The other is a details table which captures vendor, part_number, and quantity data.
I have an after insert trigger on the header table which is suppose to update a table in another database with order info and a total quantity of parts in that order.
Everything works fine except when the trigger goes to calculate the total number of parts in the details table.  What is happening is the trigger fires before the data is written to the details table and always returns NULLs for the total quantity of parts.  What's the best workaround for this?  Am I using a wrong trigger?

```
OrderHeader Table
ID           int    
TransCode    int    
CustID       int
StoreID      int
Date         datetime


OrderDetail
OrderID      int
MFG          nchar(3)   
PartNumber   nchar(35)
Qty          int


ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_Update_PRIME]
on [Cleansweep].[dbo].[OrderHeader]
after  insert
AS 
BEGIN
declare @ID as int
declare @DateInput as date
declare @CustID as int
declare @transcode as int
declare @storeID as int
declare @TotItems as int

select @ID = (select ID from inserted)
select @DateInput = (select date from inserted)
select @CustID = (select CustID from inserted)
select @transcode = (select TransCode from inserted)
select @storeID = (select StoreID from inserted)

set @TotItems = ( select SUM(qty) FROM [Cleansweep].[dbo].[OrderDetail] where OrderID = @ID ) 

if @transcode = 0
begin   
    insert into PRIME.dbo.PRIME_RepCalls (Customer, Cores)
    values (@CustID, @TotItems)
end

if @transcode = 1
begin   
    insert into PRIME.dbo.PRIME_RepCalls (Customer, NewReturns)
    values (@CustID, @TotItems))
end

END
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive that there two insert process in your DB - first one is when `insert` into `Header table`, and the second when is `insert` to `Details table`.

If you do insert Header first - than your trigger works before details of your documents were inserted in Db. That's why `SUM` can return `NULL`

Comment: I think this is exactly what's happening.  I'm just wondering what mechanics I can implement to circumvent that. I'm thinking of doing the total items calculation and storing it in the header table.

Comment: After creating `Header` and `Details` of document you may call stored procedure. For example, you may create `SP ConfirmDoc(@ID)` which will calculate fields what you need and write it in the header. Also create additional column `IsConfirmed` in `Header` table - so you will always be able to know if document was fully written to DB or not. This approach is used in most of the ERP systems that I ever saw.

Comment: Or you may create function witch will generate new ID for your document. Than you will be able to write details of document first (with generated ID). Then add header of the document. In this case your `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` will be work as it supposed to be.